# How to get an array displayed on UITableView of dates as strings converted to dates?

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a custom cell made that shows some important details of strings retrieved from Realtime Database (Firebase). This is all working well with no issues.

My problem is that I need to get the dates from those textlabels on each cell (retrieved from an array of strings, fetched from the database), convert them to dates and then calculate if it has passed more than 3 days from that date and if so, that cell would highlight with a color so user can pay attention.

I can convert strings to dates, no problems, my issue here is how to do it from an array, and to to let know the cell that the date being displayed on the textfield is older than 3 days.

I think I know what to do, which would be to convert the array to dates and then display the dates on the textlabel, instead of the string and then create a conditional to see if the date is older than 3 days, if so, highlight the cell.

My issue is that I do not have any clue how to do this, as every time I try to convert the array to date I get nil.

Could anyone give me a light or direction to go, I am a little bit new to programming, and first time doing so using TableViews.

UPDATE

This is my current code for my UITableView:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell()
        var projects = self.projectsArray[indexPath.row]
        var dates = self.projectsDateArray[indexPath.row]
        var statuses = self.projectsStatusArray[indexPath.row]
        var users = self.projectsUserArray[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = projects
        
        if indexPath.row > 0 {
            let customCell = self.projectsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: OrderManagementCell.identifier) as! OrderManagementCell
            customCell.configure(with: projects, date: dates, status: statuses, user: users)
            return customCell
        }
        
        return cell
    }
```

And this is the code to retrieve the data from realtime database:

```
func getTableViewData() {
        let ref = databaseRef.child("User_Information").child("\(dataName)").child("Projects")
        
        ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            for details in snapshot.children {
                let snap = details as! DataSnapshot
                let project = snap.value as! [String: Any]
                let date = project["Date"] as! String
                let status = project["Status"] as! String
                let user = project["User"] as! String
                self.projectsDateArray.append(date)
                self.projectsStatusArray.append(status)
                self.projectsUserArray.append(user)
                //print("\(date) \(status) \(user)")
            }
        }
    }
```

My custom cell configure code is here:

```
import UIKit

class OrderManagementCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let identifier = "OrderManagementCell"
    static func nib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: "OrderManagementCell", bundle: nil)
    }
    
    public func configure(with title: String, date: String, status: String, user: String) {
        cellTitle.text = title
        cellDate.text = date
        cellStatus.text = status
        cellUser.text = user
    }
    
    @IBOutlet var cellTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var cellDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var cellStatus: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var cellUser: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table views and collection views use a data source. That's an object that implements several methods that tell the table/collection view how many sections and rows there are, and provide cells when asked.

Typically your data source is fed by an array (or an array of arrays if you use a sectioned table/collection view.) An array of structs works well since a struct can hold properties for everything needed in your cells.

You need to set up a model that lets you configure your cells as desired.

I suggest using an array of structs that hold both date **Strings** for display and Date objects or booleans that let you decide if each cell needs to be highlighted.

You can start with an array of structs with the date string populated but the `Date` field blank. Then do a map statement on the array of structs, replacing the `Date` field with a `Date` you compute from the date String (using a DateFormatter)

We can't help you set that up unless we know what your data looks like. Edit your question to show the data structure you are currently using to hold the data for your cells, and some sample data. Also show some sample date strings, and the code you are using to convert your date Strings to Date objects. (Don't reply with comments. Add info to your original question.)

### Edit:

I created a sample struct `Person` that contains a date String property and `birthday` and `isOver18` Optional properties:

```
struct Person: CustomStringConvertible {
    let name: String
    let birthdayString: String
    var birthday: Date? = nil
    var isOver18: Bool?  = nil
    
    var description: String {
        var description = "Person(\n"
        let birthdayDisplayString = birthday?.description(with: .current) ?? "nil"
        let isOver18String = isOver18.map { $0 ? "true" : "false" } ?? "nil"
        description += "  name: \(name)\n"
        description += "  birthdayString: \(birthdayString)\n"
        description += "  birthday: \(birthdayDisplayString)\n"
        description += "  isOver18: \(isOver18String)\n"
        description += ")"
        return description
    }
}
```

And then wrote sample code that populates an array of these `Person` objects with name and date strings. I then wrote a function that maps a Person struct to a Person struct that contains it's birthday `Date` and `isOver18 properties:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Create a DateFormatter
    let formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let aFormatter = DateFormatter()
        aFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
        return aFormatter
    }()

    var people = [Person]()
    
    // A function that takes a Person struct as input and returns another Person with their `birthday` and `isOver18` properties populated.
    func addBirthdayInfo(person: Person) -> Person {
        let today = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
        
        var newPerson = person
        newPerson.birthday = formatter.date(from: person.birthdayString)
        if let birthday = newPerson.birthday,
            let date18YearsAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -18, to: today, wrappingComponents: false) {
            newPerson.isOver18 = birthday < date18YearsAgo
        }
        return newPerson
    }
    
    // Create an array of Person with only name and birthdaySring fields poulated
    func createPeople() {
        let secondsIn5Years = Double(60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 5)
        let secondsIn30Years = secondsIn5Years * 6
        let names = ["John Doe", "Bertrand Russel", "Franz Kafka", "Suzie Creamcheese", "Moon Unit Zappa", "Jose Juarez", "Hans Christian Anderson", "Boutros Boutros-Ghali", "Angela Merkel", "Élisabeth Borne"]
        for name in names {
            // Generate a random birhtdate for this person any time between 5 and 30 years ago.
            let birthdate = Date().addingTimeInterval(Double.random(in: 0-secondsIn30Years..<0-secondsIn5Years))
            let person = Person(name: name, birthdayString: formatter.string(from:birthdate))
            people.append(person)
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createPeople()
        
        // Go though the array of people and replace each struct with a stuct containing `birthday` and `isOver18` properties.
        people = people.map{ addBirthdayInfo(person: $0)}
        for person in people {
            print(person)
        }
    }
}
```

If you run that code it creates a array of Person objects, assigns random birthday strings to those `Person` objects, and then does another pass populating the `birthday` `Date` and `isOver18` `Bool` properties for each Person.

That should give you an idea of how you might write your code.

Comment: Thank you so, so much for your answer. Would the code I have added here help?

Comment: That's a start. How are you configuring your cells? (Add the code for your `configure()` method. One suggestion: Don't set up multiple arrays, each one containing a separate data element. That path leads to madness. Instead, create a single array of structs, where the struct contains all the data elements needed to show a cell.

Comment: I have updated my question with the requested code. I have tried to do an array struct, but I was having issues implementing it. I got to a point where I was so lost that I decided to do the four separately.

Comment: So the focus of your question is around how to select your cells based on the date string for that entry, but you don't show any code that attempts to implement that logic. How can we help you debug code that you don't show? I also asked you to show some sample data including a date string and the code to parse that date string. (It is frustrating to try to answer questions where the asker does not provide a complete description of the problem, and have to go back again and again and ask for more information.)

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, I did not intend on making you frustrated.
1. English is my second language, I do my best to try and explain my issue;
2. I do not have any code yet, because the code I was using simply wasn't working, so I gave up and came here for help. At this point in time, I am not yet converting the fetched date string from the database to my code. I am truly sorry if what I have said was not explicit.

If there is a list of everything you would need to be able to help me, please let me know and I will provide all data and code I have to make that happen.

Comment: In order to compare the dates you get from your database to some other date (3 days old would be comparing to the current date) you need to convert your date String to a Date object. To do that you need to create a configure a DateFormatter. Edit your question to show some sample date strings you are getting out of your database.

Comment: Maintaining multiple arrays of single items (an array of dates, an array of usernames, an array of titles, etc) is almost always bad, because you then have to maintain those arrays. It is almost always better to have a single array of structs where each struct contains the info you need for a cell. I suggest stopping and restructuring your code to use an array of structs. Get that working, then move to highlighting cells based on date, etc.

Comment: Will do, thank you!

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Comment: It worked, thank you. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: So you have a DateFormatter that is able to parse the date strings you are getting from your database?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, it was a long weekend (thanksgiving). 

Yes, at the moment, I am converting the strings to date and I am getting the current day and time and get the difference between days just fine. Thank you!